# com.sun.jdi.InternalException: Got error code in reply:502 occurred invoking method

Tags: java, eclipse, remote-debugging, http-error, jdi

I am trying to debug a remote service and keep getting this error in eclipse debugger.I initially thought that it is a network issue and setup the debugging environment on a remote VM but the issue still persists. Please, help me in resolving it.

Comment: provide more detail about your code, when and what